# Sigma Algebra property

Tags: measure-theory, proof-explanation, borel-sets

Let $\mathcal{C}=\{(-\infty,x]:x\in\mathbb{R}\}$ and $\mathcal{C}_0=\{[a,b]:-\infty<a<b<\infty\}$. I want to show that $\sigma(\mathcal{C})=\sigma(\mathcal{C}_0)$. I think the general idea of the proof is to show that $A\subseteq \mathcal{C}\implies A\subseteq\sigma(\mathcal{C}_0)\implies\sigma(\mathcal{C}_0)\subseteq\sigma(\mathcal{C})$ and vice versa. My difficulties lie in understanding why if $A\subseteq \mathcal{C}\implies A\subseteq\sigma(\mathcal{C}_0)$ is true, then, $\sigma(\mathcal{C}_0)\subseteq\sigma(\mathcal{C})$. 
Can someone help me with this step?

Comment: The general idea is to show that $\mathcal C \subseteq \mathcal C_0$, which implies that $\mathcal C \subseteq \sigma(\mathcal C_0)$, and consequently $\sigma(\mathcal C) \subseteq \sigma(\mathcal C_0)$.  Then show the opposite containment $\mathcal C_0 \subseteq \mathcal C$, which implies that $\mathcal C_0 \subseteq \sigma(\mathcal C)$, and consequently $\sigma(\mathcal C_0) \subseteq \sigma(\mathcal C)$

Comment: The opposite implication is what I meant  by "vice versa", but thanks for the clear explanation :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $ (-\infty,x]= \cup_{n=1}^{\infty}[-n,x]$. As $ [-n,x]\in C_0 \implies \cup_{n=1}^{\infty}[-n,x] \in \sigma(C_0)\implies \sigma(C)\subseteq  \sigma(C_0).\\$

$[a,b]= [a,\infty)\cap(-\infty,b] $ and since
$(-\infty,a] \in \sigma(C) \implies(-\infty,a]^c= (a,\infty) \in \sigma(C). \\$
$[a,\infty)= \cap_{n=1}^{\infty}(a-\frac{1}{n}, \infty) \in \sigma(C)\\$.
$\implies [a,\infty)\cap(-\infty,b]  = [a,b] \in \sigma(C)\implies \sigma(C_0) \subseteq \sigma(C).\\$

Comment: My doubt is actually the last implication, that is, when you show that every element of $C$ belongs to $\sigma(C_0)$, then, why $\sigma(C)\subseteq\sigma(C_0)$?

Comment: @StatisticalShibainu If $\mathcal C \subseteq \sigma(\mathcal C_0)$, then $\sigma(\mathcal C_0)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathcal C$. Therefore $\sigma(\mathcal C)$, which is the **smallest** $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathcal C$, must be contained in $\sigma(\mathcal C_0)$. Putting it another way, $\sigma(\mathcal C)$ is the intersection of all $\sigma$-algebras containing $\mathcal C$, and $\sigma(\mathcal C_0)$ is one of those $\sigma$-algebras.

Comment: Because $C$ is the generating set for the $\sigma(C)$ and every element of $\sigma(C)$ is some complement or countable union or both of sets in $C$. Since, $\sigma(C_0)$ contains every set in $C$ hence, the complement, countable union or both of elements in $C$ are in $\sigma(C_0)$ because $\sigma(C_0)$ being a sigma algebra is closed w.r.t. complement and countable union.

Comment: Now I understand the argument clearly, thanks a lot guys:)